Javascript / AJAX code for AI quiz generator
I am trying to see the Javascript / AJAX which gets triggered
In the web page =>
https://www.heuristi.ca/tools/free-ai-quiz-generator
when we select Tab Website, paste a link and press the button =>
Generate Quiz from Input
Is it possible to customize this website to our own needs?
Which function script should I call when user presses the button ( Generate Quiz from Input ?
Can you please help?
I have already tried Chrome debugging, but did not reach anywhere

Is it possible to customize this website to our own needs? - is it your website? do you have the source code? Looks like a paid website. Are you trying to use someone elses intellectual property for yourself?
